# Eclipse SWT Virtual Composite Question

Tags: eclipse, swt, virtual, composite

Is it possible to create a virtual composite using SWT, i.e. one could scroll horizontally or vertically beyond the maximum display area of the composite?

I want the length and height of my widgets (images) to stay constant regardless what size the composite is changed to.

If there are 50 images to display and only 10 can be viewed at once when the composite is maximized, I want to be able to scroll right to display the remaining images.

I could not get ScrolledComposite to display anything.

I am able to see the first few images when I just use a composite and attach a horizontal scrollbar.

Thanks.

Comment: It turns out that ScrolledComposite is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean a [scrolled composite](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/Scrollacontrolinascrolledcomposite.htm)?

Comment: I want to be able to display n number of widgets in one row.  when I try to do this I can only scroll the length of my max screen length.